# VBA - "FORMAT" function isn't recongnised on 1 computer

Tags: excel, vba, format

I've coded something in VBA to help my co-workers and it's working on 8 computers but on this one computer, everytime I try to start the code, it gives me an error.

Sorry I'm translating from French into English but the error is:

Compilation error:
Project or library isn't found

The actual code is:

```
'           ============================================
'           === TRAITEMENT DES PRODUITS DU GROUPE 10 ===
'           ========== FOURNISSEURS STANDARDS ==========
'           ============================================
            Case 10
            Select Case var_Prix
                Case Is < 25
                    Range(COLLISTE & var_Ligne).Value = Format(99999, "#,####0.0000")
                    Range(COLPRIX2 & var_Ligne).Value = Format(var_Prix / (0.5 - TRANSPORT), "#,####0.0000")
                    Range(COLPRIX3 & var_Ligne).Value = Format(var_Prix / (0.52 - TRANSPORT), "#,####0.0000")
                    Range(COLPRIX4 & var_Ligne).Value = Format(var_Prix / (0.55 - TRANSPORT), "#,####0.0000")
                    Range(COLPRIX5 & var_Ligne).Value = Format(var_Prix / (0.6 - TRANSPORT), "#,####0.0000")
<the code continues>
```

and it has Format highlighted. Seems like the "Format library" isn't installed but I've tried Google and apparently "Format" is installed with windows or office.

Comment: `Format` isn't a library - it's a built in VB function. Does that co-worker have an add-in with a public `Format` function?

Comment: sorry, I'm not a programmer. I'm just interested in the subject and I try to do stuff on my own (while using this forum from times to time to help me understand). That being said, how would I find out if he has an add-in with public format function?

Comment: Check (on the problem computer) if there is any library marked missing under (VBE menu) Tools, References.

Comment: Libraries are:
- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

On all my other computers the versions are 16.0 instead of 15.0. Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As JKP asked, are there any references marked as "missing"? A missing Ref can cause unpredictable behaviour in other referenced libraries.
As a temporary solution, try forcing the reference by putting VBA. before the format, like
= VBA.Format(99999, "#,####0.0000")
This normally works.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue recently. Cause was 'something' had disabled the "Analysis Toolpack - VBA" Add-in.

Answer (score 0):

so just had this issue. The solution we found was to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime and Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library back to the References - VBA Project selection.
Not sure which one actually fixed it. But both made the rest of my file work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).